# При сборке rpm пакета gscan2pdf на CentOS 7 выдает ошибку (Неверный код возврата из /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.ciLtSg (%install))

Tags: linux

```
Error on file "/root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/gscan2pdf-2.13.2-1.el7.alteros.x86_64//usr/share/applications/gscan2pdf.desktop": No such file or directory
ошибка: Неверный код возврата из /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.ciLtSg (%install)


Ошибки сборки пакетов:
    Неверный код возврата из /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.ciLtSg (%install)
```